# I am trying to setup a fault tolerance university campus network

Tags: cisco

[image: My vlan concept]

I am creating a network between tutor vlan 10 and student vlan 20 consisting of 3 campuses. Is it possible to connect the campuses together in a fault tolerance VLAN network?

Comment: If you're responsible for a multi-national university network, you should probably hire a consultant to plan this out.

Comment: Is this a real problem or a homework problem? If it's homework - that's fine. But you need to tell us what you think the problem is. You've supplied the diagram which is a good start, but we're not going to do your homework for you. We will help with a specific problem that you're stuck on though.

Comment: Also your diagram needs a legend. What are the coloured dots representing?

Comment: This is from Cisco Packet Tracer. The red and green dots signify network connectivity. Green signifies that traffic is able to flow across the link and red signifies that traffic is not able to flow across the link, due to misconfiguration, interface being shutdown, etc.

Comment: No, it's not homework. Just a getting used to packet tracer so I'm just learning my way through the software like constructing different kinds of networks mostly VLANs so basically I just create different types of scenarios like universities, work, home network etc.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of problems I see straight off the bat:

You have two routers labelled Scotland and England. But these are countries, not places you can install a router. So where is your router going to live specifically? And how are they connected? Is there a direct fibre running all the way from England to Scotland? Or is it a tunnel over the internet? Maybe MPLS?

You also have London and Newcastle connected to the same router. London and Newcastle are 150 miles apart. You would not share a router between them. You would have one router in Newcastle, one in London and one in Glasgow.

If you are creating tunnels over the internet with your networks then you would typically create a mesh between them (London connects to Glasgow and Newcastle, etc). If they are connected via MPLS then the MPLS provider would take care of that for you. If you are directly connecting them via fibre then you probably wouldn't be asking this question on here. You would then run a routing protocol (iBGP) to keep everything in check.

As for vlans, I don't see them marked on your switches so I don't know if you're doing 802.1q or port-based vlans, or maybe 802.1x with 802.1q so I can't actually provide you feedback. Except unless you are doing one gigantic Layer 2 network between all three campuses, your vlans are going to be restricted to each physical location and the fact that there are three campuses is basically irrelevant.